# Create file name based on the functions arguments and the content based on the condition in the function - R

Tags: r, subset

I would like to create inside of a function some files which names derives from the arguments of the function. The file content will be created based on some conditions from a file which get read inside the body function

```
  set.seed(123)
  dt <- data.frame(col1_mean = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE), col2_n = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE), Col3 = c("ID1", "ID1","ID2", "ID1","ID2", "ID1","ID2", "ID1",  "ID1", "ID1"), col4 = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE))
  get_file = function (var1, var2) {
  #create file name based on the var1 and var2 and the content based on the condition in dt
  paste0("my_text_", var1, "_", var2) =   dt[Col3 == paste0(var2)]  # select only rows with ID given by var2
  
  }
```

For instance, get_file("AB", "ID1") should create the file: my_text_AB_ID1 which will be a subset of the dt1 containing only the rows with ID1 in Col3.

The code above doesn't work. Any idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `assign` however note that it is not a good practice to write objects to global environment from within a function.

```
get_file = function (var1, var2) {

  assign(paste0("my_text_", var1, "_", var2), dt[dt$Col3 == var2, ],
         envir = parent.frame())
}


get_file("AB", "ID1")
my_text_AB_ID1
#   col1_mean col2_n Col3 col4
#1          3      5  ID1    9
#2          3      3  ID1    3
#4          2      9  ID1    1
#6          5      3  ID1    5
#8          6     10  ID1    7
#9          9      7  ID1    9
#10        10     10  ID1    9
```